# how to use spring webclient properly in the tenant context

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am using the Spring WebClient (org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient) in order to implement some non-blocking behaviour.

```
        Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponse = 
            webClient
            .get(...).exchange();

        clientResponse.subscribe((response) -> {
             //--- unfortunately my tenant context is lost here !!! Someone knows the right solution?
        });
```

However my tenant-context gets lost once the response arrives (of course, we are in a new thread).

Here is the documentation of how to implement common asynchronous tasks within the tenant-context: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/multi-tenancy/multi-tenancy-thread-context/

However, I couldn't find the recommended way how to remain the tenant-context using Spring webflux (using the WebClient).

Comment: Are you only using the reactive framework for performing a request within your backend, or is your entire backend itself running on the reactive stack?

The Cloud SDK applies a `javax.servlet.Filter` to populate a `ThreadContext` on an inbound request. Such servlet filters might not be recognised in your specific setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The SAP Cloud SDK destroys a `ThreadContext` at the end of an operation. This is done to prevent it from leaking e.g. when the thread is re-used.

If:

- the context is passed to an asynchronous operation
- but the "parent" operation is done before the asynchronous operation starts

the `ThreadContext` will not be available in the asynchronous operation. That is what is happening when using the `WebClient`.

This is not true for custom properties, the SDK does not clear them. But that also means that you have to clear them yourself to ensure they don't leak when the thread is being re-used.

I'd recommend not to use the multi tenancy features of the SDK in such cases. Still, I'll leave my below answer in for context.

---

You can transfer the SAP Cloud SDK's ThreadContext to any new Thread if and only if you have control:

- Before the new Thread is created
- The operation that will be run asynchronously that requires the context
- **Edit**: The parent thread (context) still exists

I am not too familiar with WebFlux, but I'll assume that:

- `clientResponse.subscribe` runs in the parent Thread
- And the lambda is executed in the asynchronous Thread

Given that, the following should transfer the `ThreadContext` to be present in the lambda:

```java
ThreadContextExecutor executor = new ThreadContextExecutor();

clientResponse.subscribe((response) -> 
    executor.execute(() ->
       {
          // your code goes here, the ThreadContext should be available
       }
    )
);
```

You would have to do this at every point where an operation is running in a new Thread. As Artem pointed out, currently there is no feature in the SDK for this that would achieve the same automagically.

---

I think it is also possible to define a custom `ExecutorService` that Spring will use to create and run new Threads. In a custom executor you could encapsulate this wrapping logic once for all operations.

Comment: I have tried your idea of using the ThreadContextExecutor, unfortunately the ThreadContext is not available (the properites-HashMap is empty) inside the lambda :-(

Comment: Okay, that means that (at least) one of the two assumptions of my answer doesn't hold true. I'll check if I can get a quick example to run, maybe we can use the [Context feature of Project Reactor 3.1.0](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) to make this use case work.

Comment: I unit tested the above code and can confirm that it works, IF a `ThreadContext` exists at the exact point in time when `ThreadContextExecutor executor` is being created.

Comment: You can find the full code here: https://gist.github.com/MatKuhr/82c6f22b2f78830883b5d9a1c647dae2

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can confirm that it works!

Comment: A small addition: the property "some-property" of your example remains, all other properties however, that were already set before (e.g. "com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.AuthTokenThreadContextListener:authToken") are lost. 
But it is possible to save them using a different property-name in the thread-context, then they also remain.

Comment: Right, that is very strange. Within `clientResponse.subscribe( ... )` the "normal" properties like `tenant` and `authToken` are lost. Only the "custom" properties are retained.

By contrast, when I replace `clientResponse.subscribe( ... )` with `new Thread( ... ).start()` the all properties are retained. Honestly I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I expanded my answer to point out why it doesn't work with the standard properties. Overall, I'd recommend to not use the multi tenancy features of the Cloud SDK until there is dedicated support for this feature

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Cloud SDK APIs support Spring Boot and currently don't support Spring Webflux out of the box. You'll probably see all sorts of errors if using the SDK APIs with reactive Spring development. On the other hand, as Matthias showed workarounds might be possible for certain use-cases.

We consider adding Spring WebFlux support in the future. It probably won't happen this year (in 2021).